# How to implement RBAC (Role Based Access Control) in ASP.NET web forms?

Tags: asp.net, rbac

I found [this great article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/875547/Custom-Roles-Based-Access-Control-RBAC-in-ASP-NET) on how to implement RBAC (Role Based Access Control) in ASP.NET MVC.

How can I implement it in an existing ASP.NET web forms application?

Comment: What do you mean "how to implement it"? What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can try Casbin.NET: https://github.com/casbin/Casbin.NET

Answer (score 1):

you can use Casbin.NET, the open source project for implement RBAC in multiple languages and platforms, for more information search on github.

Answer (score 0):

This might be help you for Asp.net Web forms.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/roles/role-based-authorization-cs